# How to call a XML element using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

My Xml has below data.
 I need to get Type,Headline which contains 'step' in Headline and step number

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<Testlog>
        <Event Timestamp="27-Dec-2012 04:25:12.247 PM" Type="Script End" Headline="Script end [DSE.DSEBalanceInquiry_FC.DseBalanceInquiry_FC_Test_003]" Result="WARNING">
        <Property script_name="DSE.DSEBalanceInquiry_FC.DseBalanceInquiry_FC_Test_003"/>
        <Property script_id="DSE.DSEBalanceInquiry_FC.DseBalanceInquiry_FC_Test_003.java"/>
    </Event>

    <Event Timestamp="27-Dec-2012 04:25:10.747 PM" Type="Export Event" Headline="getProperty on the List ABC: Trace Facility" Result="PASS">
        <Property line_number="434"/>
        <Property script_name="DSE.DSEBalanceInquiry_FC.DseBalanceInquiry_FC_Test_003"/>
    </Event>

<Event Timestamp="27-Dec-2012 04:16:33.226 PM" Type="General" Headline="_FRMWK.SystemLibrary.Sys_TmxProcesses logStepBegin: Step: 2; Action: node; Narrative: Node: &apos;DseBalanceInquiry_FC.RST_ACU_DEF(T)&apos;  &apos;Use ACU to Import the default ACU settings xml file.  When importing, all the checkboxes are checked in the Application list.  i.e. Perform the RestoreAcuDefaults keyword  &apos;; TestName: DseBalanceInquiry_FC_Test_003" Result="INFORMATION">
        <Property script_name="DSE.DSEBalanceInquiry_FC.DseBalanceInquiry_FC_Test_003"/>
        <Property line_number="61"/>
        <Property script_id="DSE.DSEBalanceInquiry_FC.DseBalanceInquiry_FC_Test_003.java"/>
    </Event>
    <Event Timestamp="27-Dec-2012 04:16:33.335 PM" Type="General" Headline="_FRMWK.SystemLibrary.Sys_TmxProcesses logStepBegin: Step: 2.001; Action: ImportACU; Narrative:             Import ACU settings based on &apos;&apos; ; TestName: DseBalanceInquiry_FC_Test_003" Result="INFORMATION">
        <Property script_name="DSE.DSEBalanceInquiry_FC.DseBalanceInquiry_FC_Test_003"/>
        <Property line_number="64"/>
        <Property script_id="DSE.DSEBalanceInquiry_FC.DseBalanceInquiry_FC_Test_003.java"/>
    </Event>

 </Testlog>
```

Edited the code. This gives me list of headlines which has step, If i want to get the step number in separate row, how i can achieve it?

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

     <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

     <xsl:template match="/">
     <html>
      <body>
     <h2>Report</h2>
    <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
     <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
     <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
     <th style="text-align:left">Step</th>
     <th style="text-align:left">Headline</th>
   </tr>

  <xsl:for-each select="Testlog/Event[contains(@Headline, 'Step:')]">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@Type"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@Result"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@Step"/></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="@Headline"/></td>
   </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly do you want to add to the result? You already *have* the Type and the Headline, alongside the Result.

Comment: My apologies for not providing proper data. In the Headline, which has  "STEP" in the headline i need those details to be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want to add the events whose headline contains "Step:" to the report as additional table rows, then replace this line:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Testlog/Event[@Result='WARNING']">
```

with:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Testlog/Event[@Result='WARNING' or contains(@Headline, 'Step:')]">
```

If not, then please clarify some more.

---

> one more question , If i want to get the step number in separate row,
>   how i can achieve it? –

I think you mean a separate *column*, not row? If so, add another `<td>` element to the table (within the `for-each` loop):

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(@Headline, 'Step:'), ';')"/></td>
```

Then add a corresponding `<th>` element to the table header above.

Comment: Ya got it. Thank you for your answer and patience:)

Comment: Michael i have one more question ,  If i want to get the step number in separate row, how i can achieve it?