# XSLT function " substring-before " / " substring-after "

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have following XML code

```
<Testlog>   
 <Event Type="General" 
   Headline="Sys_TmxProcesses: Step: 1; Action:" 
   Result="INFORMATION">
  </Event>
 <Event Type="General" 
   Headline="Test_013 testMain: Step 1 Passed" 
   Result="INFORMATION">
  </Event>
<Event Type="General" 
   Headline="logStepBegin: Step: 1.001; Action:" 
   Result="INFORMATION">
  </Event>      
 <Event Type="General" 
   Headline="onErrorExit: Step 4.001 Failed" 
   Result="WARNING">
  </Event>  
 <Event Type="Script End" 
   Headline="Script end [DSE.DseBalanceInquiry_FC_Test_013]" 
   Result="WARNING">
  </Event>

 <Event Type="Script End" 
   Headline="Script end [DSE.DseBalanceInquiry_FC_Test_001]" 
   Result="FAIL">
  </Event>     
</Testlog>
```

Now i'd like to only grab the 
1.Type
2.Result
3.'Step number' Which i have to get from the Headline
4.Headline
5.'Step Status' which i have to get from the Headline, which is after the step number.

the following xslt gives values for Type,Result and Headlines.
But i am unable to get 
(1)Step Number (only number should be displayed) 
(2)Step Status(Passed/Failed should display not the number)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
 <body>
  <h2>Report</h2>
   <table border="1">
   <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th style="text-align:left">Type</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Result</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Step Number</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Headline</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Step Status</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="Testlog/Event[@Result='WARNING' or @Result='FAIL' or contains(@Headline, 'Step ')]">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@Type"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@Result"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@Headline,'Step ')"/></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="@Headline"/></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@Headline,'Step ')"/></td>
   </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989136/how-to-call-a-xml-element-using-xslt and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991331/reading-a-xml-text-and-placing-it-in-row-using-xslt

Comment: Sagar, please stop asking essentially the same question over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should nest substring-after calls to parse step number and status

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
 <body>
  <h2>Report</h2>
   <table border="1">
   <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th style="text-align:left">Type</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Result</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Step Number</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Headline</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Step Status</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="Testlog/Event[@Result='WARNING' or @Result='FAIL' or contains(@Headline, 'Step ')]">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@Type"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@Result"/></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(@Headline,'Step '),' ')"/></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="@Headline"/></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(@Headline,'Step '),' ')"/></td>
   </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```